# Problem in polygon division using the union tool from QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, union

I am trying to overlay two polygon layers using the union tool from QGIS, to then compute the areas from the resulting polygons. However, in the resulting layer some polygons are not divided as expected. Attached you will find two figures showing the layers I want to overlay (orange and green) and the resulting one (pink). Has anyone had a similar problem? Do you know what is due to?

[image: Two layers to overlay][image: Resulting layer]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @abo! Looks like the orientation for both polygon layers is slightly different, hence why there's a misalignment. Did you use the **Vector Grid** tool to create them?

Comment: From the pink picture it seems that the union fails when a green polygon overlays 4 orange polygons, and at least at one side borders of both polygons are nearly congruent. Then the cut perpendicular to that side fails. Is that right? Maybe a precision issue? Or due to the sequence with which the algorithm processes such situations?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
I've used the option “voronoi polygons” from the vector geometry tools to create the polygons. In my opinion, @Detlev 's description of the problem is correct. Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks again.

Comment: Did you check topology of your both input polygons by "Topology Checker" before apply union?